# Regex: Obtener lo que está dentro de texto y comillas y que no tome las comillas

Tags: c#, regex

Soy nuevo usando regex y estoy intentando obtener lo que esta dentro de nombre="Brian" en este caso me devolvería Brian solamente. Ya logré obtener lo que esta dentro de las comillas aunque de una manera no tan buena. Yo hago lo siguiente:

```
List<String> nombres = new List<String>();
string list = "nombre=\"Jorge\"  nombre=\"Martin\"  nombre=\"Juan\"  nombre=\"Brian\"";
string regex = "\"([^\"]*)\"";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(list, regex))
    {
        nombres.Add(match.ToString().Replace("\"", ""));
    }
listBoxNombres.DataSource = nombres;
```

Con ese código logré obtener lo que está  dentro de las comillas, pero quiero obtener lo que esta dentro de nombre="" porque si por ejemplo hay un apellido="" también tomaría lo que está dentro de las comillas y no quiero eso.
Y si tienen algo para que no tome las comillas también se los agradecería.

Comment: y probaste poniendo `nombre=` al inicio de tu expresión regular?